# Random outofboundsexception being thrown for no reason?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm using LWJGL and Slick2D for a game I'm making. I can't seem to get it to draw the way I want it to be draw so I came up with an idea just to make my own drawing method. Basically it takes a image, a x, and a y and it goes through each pixel in the image, gets the color, then draws the image with the parameter x plus the x pixel it's on to get the position that the pixel is suppost to be drawn on. Same idea with the y. Although if the alpha channel isn't 255 for the pixel it doesn't draw it, although I'll fix that later. The problem is that whenever I run my code I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -2044". I'm really confused. I'm hoping someone can figure out why this is happening.

```
private void DrawImage(Image image, int xP, int yP)
{
    //xP And yP Are The Position Parameters

    //Begin Drawing Individual Pixels
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    //Going Across The X And The Y Coords Of The Image
    for (int x = 1; x <= image.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 1; y <= image.getHeight(); y++)
        {   
            //Define A Color Object
            Color color = null;

            //Set The Color Object And Check If The Color Is Completly Solid Before Rendering
            if ((color = image.getColor(x, y)).a == 255)
            {
                //Bind The Color
                color.bind();

                //Draw The Color At The Coord Parameters And The X/Y Coord Of The Individual Pixel
                glVertex2i(xP + x - 1, yP + y - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Comment: First of all, do you have a line number for where the error is occurring (if you know exactly where it throwing the exception it makes it much easier to debug)? Secondly, I don't see any explicit references to arrays in this part of your code -- look to see where you are accessing arrays and then check and see if any variables or constants being used as an index can have values that are outside the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is assuming that the texture is an array of data.

I have a feeling it is the `getColor()` method. Your for loop runs through and will use the height and width values. An array usually starts off with 0 and width and height are just array counts typically. So I can see when you reach HEIGHT, that the texture array will throw an exception.

Try removing the `<=` part and replace it with `<`

EXAMPLE:

`for (int x = 1; x < image.getWidth(); x++)`

It may also help you to start off with zero so you can get the entire image.

EXAMPLE

`for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++)`

Here is a link on [arrays](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_arrays.html).

This way, when you ask for the color at whatever position, it will never ask for a color reaching beyond what is in the texture array. Hopefully I made sense.